# Information showing up only on the first page

Tags: footnotes, line-numbering

I'm running latex files on my device. These are the first few lines of the file:

```
\documentclass[sigconf, anonymous, review]{acmart}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./}{Charts/}}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
```

The problem is when I run it I get red line numbers only in the first page. But my colleagues get it on every page. We use the exact same latex file and also the same acmart.cls (latest one) file on the local directory.
I also had this problem before in another case. The conference information for others showed up in all the pages, and for mine it was only in the first page. I don't know what's the problem.
I'm running this command:
'pdflatex filename.txt'

My latex version is:
'pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
kpathsea version 6.3.0'

Could someone please tell me what causes the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: With your example my simple document using `\lipsum` doesn't show line numbers nowhere... So, please create an example (compilable with everything needed) that shows your actual problem. Also I don't know what the footnotes tag has to do with your question.

Comment: The conference information should shown up as header notes in all the pages (as it does when others run it). But on my device it only shows up in the first page.

Comment: The problem in my test was that I had no maketitle command because I supposed doesn't really needed... But it is needed for this functionality. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that removing the package `fullpage` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[review]{acmart}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./}{Charts/}}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{fullpage} Commented out

\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{test}
\author{test}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle


\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Also moved the `hyperref` to be loaded last.

Consider using geometry package with the appropriate settings (but better just don't touch this documentclasse's features and just remove it)